# iOS App not running in background mode on actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, core-location

I am using Core Location to get location. it is working pretty fine in foreground, But not getting location in background mode. I have apparently done all the steps like, enabling location background service from capabilities, and plist configuiration.

[image]

and here is plist file
[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
location = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
self.locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
if (osVersion >= 8.0)
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
else
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(checkCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I am testing on iPad mini with OS 9.0.1

**P.S : Background mode is working on simulator**

Comment: FYI don't add check for the OS version. The proper thing to do is to check to see if the API exists.

Comment: Why do you only call `startUpdatingLocation` if it's an older version of iOS? You need to call that for all versions.

Comment: Yes I need to make it work on iOS7 to iOS9